# Fastest way to check for the highest filename in sequence with Batch file?

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I'm attempting to use a batch file to keep all files in a particular folder numbered sequentially (0,1,2,...). To do this I first require knowing what the highest number in this sequence is so I can append the non-sequentially named files to the end of the list. For example, I may have the following files:

0.png

1.jpg

2.jpg

3.png

file_51.jpg

pictureabc.png

This would return a result of 3 as that is the last filename in sequence. I would then be able to find the remaining files (not sure the best way to do this either) and number them starting at 4.

The only solution I have come up with so far is using an infinite goto loop that stops when no filename including that number exists.

```
set count=0
:loop
if exist %count%.* set /a count+=1 & goto loop
```

This solution is highly inefficient however and takes almost a minute for 100 thousand images. I'm looking for a solution that will be able to achieve this in under 10 seconds if possible.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "nextFile=0" & for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
        dir /a-d /b ^| findstr  /b /r /x 
                       /c:"[1-9][0-9]*\.[^.]*" 
                       /c:"[1-9][0-9]*"
                       /c:"0" 
    ') do if %%~na geq !nextFile! set /a "nextFile=%%~na+1"
    endlocal & set "nextFile=%nextFile%"

    echo Next file will be: %nextFile%
```

This just uses a `dir` command to retrieve the list of all files, filtered with `findstr` to only get those with numeric name. The rest is just compare the file name against the previous max value.

**Edited** - This should work fast enough

```dos
@if (@This === @IsBatch) 
@echo off
    rem Start of batch zone ----------------------------------------------
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f %%a in ('
        dir /a-d /b /o-d 
        ^| findstr /r /x /c:"[0-9][0-9]*\.[^.]*" /c:"[0-9][0-9]*" 
        ^| cscript //nologo //e:jscript "%~f0" 
    ') do set "nextFile=%%a"

    echo next file will be %nextFile%

    exit /b
@end
    // Start of JScript zone ---------------------------------------------
    var inputStream = WScript.StdIn;
    var max = 0, value ;
    while(!WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream) {
        value = parseInt( inputStream.ReadLine().split('.')[0], 10 );
        if ( value >= max ) max = value + 1;
    }
    WScript.StdOut.WriteLine( max );
```

This is an hybrid batch/jscript file. Saved as `.cmd` file, it uses a `dir` command to retrieve the list of files, a `findstr` to leave only the files with numbered names and then the native JScript engine to extract the numbers and search for the greatest value.

Comment: This also unfortunately takes a little longer than the goto approach, which is surprising. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: @Jimpi27, yes, i have realized this morning the number the images you are processing and started reevaluating the answer. Is it possible that you have holes/missing files in the file list?

Comment: @MC_ND yes missing numbers are part of what I am hoping to check for with this program. I will also be making separate batch files for different events like a file being created, deleted or renamed in the directory. These batch files are all being run by a c# program's FileSystemWatcher that will run in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the fastest way:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set lastNum=0
for /L %%a in (1,1,9) do (
   for %%b in (%%a*.*) do (
      if %%~Nb gtr !lastNum! (
         set lastNum=%%~Nb
      )
   )
)
echo Last numbered file: %lastNum%
```

**EDIT**: *New method added*

Previous method depends on the number of existent files, so it is not as fast as I expected...

The new method below takes almost the same time no matter the number of files:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "names="
for /L %%i in (1,1,9) do set "names=!names! %%i*.*"
dir /B /A-D /O-D %names% 2> NUL | ( set /P "lastNum=" & set lastNum ) > lastNum.txt
for /F "tokens=2 delims==." %%a in (lastNum.txt) do set "lastNum=%%a"
del lastNum.txt
echo Last numbered file: %lastNum%
```

Previous method *may* fail if more than one of the last files have the same created time, but this point may be fixed if needed.

Comment: This looks more like what I want to do, but it unfortunately takes about 50% longer than my original approach.

Comment: Ops! You are right (although your method stops at the first "hole" in the file list). I added a new method in my answer...

Answer (score 0):

sorry - but the last method by Aacini works really bad. Actually it does not find the highest number, but the file created (not modified) last. It would be great to know how to fix this!

Stopping at hole can be fixed with iterations (yeah 2 lines of code for each subsequent hole).

- here is how to iterate...

  set count=1234 ::starting number

  :loop

  if exist %count%.img set /a count+=1 & goto loop

  set /a count+=1

  if exist %count%.img set /a count+=1 & goto loop

  set /a count+=1

  if exist %count%.img set /a count+=1 & goto loop

  set /a count=%count%-2

need to reduce the count at the end again. This could be made much longer of course but then it will slow down if you iterate 1000 times...